# How can I navigate and mine hell safely?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria 1.0.6, in the underworld (eg, hell):

- ash no longer falls down when unsupported
- mining a hellstone block produces a block of lava
- you can no longer place bricks where lava is - previously this could be used to "block over" lava pools, to dry them up or tunnel through them

What's are some good (or efficient) mining techniques for :

- mining hellstone?
- creating navigation tunnels?
- for crossing chasms of lava?

In light of the changes? We have this question [How do I mine safely in the underworld without Ash falling on me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/how-do-i-mine-safely-in-the-underworld-without-ash-falling-on-me) but it no longer applies with the updates.

Comment: Have you considered obsidian skin potions?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I agree. Since the ash change, I've tried everything. Obsidian skin is the only way to mine hellstone efficiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems with hell and several ways to overcome them.

**Hellstone**

- Wearing an [Obsidian skull](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Obsidian_Skull) will stop you being bunt from standing on it.
- Putting sand on top of the block before mining will remove the lava that is created.
- The buildings in hell give an excellent vantage point for mining the hellstone through the wall.

**Lava**

- [Rocket boots](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Rocket_Boots) allow you to cross large lava lakes easily, they are sold by the npc [Goblin Tinkerer](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Goblin_Tinkerer).
- [Grappling hooks](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Grappling_hook) or [Ivy whips](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Ivy_Whip) work in similar ways.
- Placing sand above the lava will remove it when the sand falls into it, but you have to build up from the bottom.
- [Water walking potions](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Water_Walking_Potion) also allow you to walk on lava without being hurt.
- There is a trick with [flippers](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Flipper) that allow you to swim *above* the lava.

Comment: Don't forget obsidian skin potions for lava immunity!

Comment: This answer needs updated for 1.1 — sand no longer destroys lava and rocket boots are no longer dropped by goblins.

Answer (score 8):

I've had good success mining with something (a glitch?) a friend and I found:

**Hellstone**
If you mine to the bottom of hell, so your player is standing on the bottom of the screen, you can throw Dynamite or bombs on the ground and the blocks off-screen will break. It seems like it keeps track of at least some of the blocks off-screen. You can then fill that area with lava and expand it with bombs or dynamite. Note: The area CAN fill up, the lava doesn't disappear so make sure you make it deep before you start mining. :)

Then, we usually just mine out the ash between the bottom of the hellstone and the bottom of the map and let the lava fall off-screen while mining beside it. We also mine from bottom to top.

**Tunneling**
Because of the way we mine, we usually start by making a tunnel straight down through the ash and avoiding hellstone. Then, it just expands across the bottom based on how much hellstone we mine and how much we have to expand the off-screen "pool".

**Crossing Chasms**
I usually just use the extra ash I've collected to make a 1 square "bridge" across.

Answer (score 1):

For mining hellstone, first make a pit below the hellstone. Then mine it from a safe distance.

This is pretty much all I have in the way of tips though, so I advise going on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I just use my ivy wip or grappling hook to get a close but safe distance then mine it then I break the ash of the lava created lowest level and make a tunnel to the open area until the lava drains out then I get the hell stone.

Answer (score -2):

Try wings! They can fly you across. Harpy wings are the best. Or make a grappling hook from iron chains and hooks found by killing piranhas or skeletons. Then you can grapple across. But if you did, practice using it first.

Comment: Don't post an answer if you're not adding anything new. Wings are not available before hard mode.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer To be fair, the question does not specify pre-hardmode, and navigating hell once the new enemies types spawn is significantly more difficult without wings.

Comment: @MageXy On the other hand, the question _does_ specify version 1.06; which is before most(all?) of that was added AFAIK.