# A good tactic for mining hellstone?

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I navigate and mine hell safely?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31295/how-can-i-navigate-and-mine-hell-safely)

I'm wondering if there's a good tactic for mining hellstone. Since I have full Shadow armor, and still I get killed damn easily by mobs in Underworld, is there something I'm missing?
Should I get some special equipment?

Comment: IMO, this question is a subset of [How can I navigate and mine hell safely?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31295/how-can-i-navigate-and-mine-hell-safely).

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it.

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to the site!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Obsidian skin potions and water breathing potions are a great combination, as they allow you to mine from within the lava, where the only enemy you have to worry about are bone dragons.